# Exploding textarea contents by new line using \n but array not being created

Tags: php, arrays, codeigniter

I am using `\n` to try and explode the contents of a textarea by new line. However, the array is not being created and it's just lumping them together. I've tried making them commas separated and it works fine, is `\n` not what I want to be using?

The textarea contains something like:

```
QWERTY
ASDFGH
ZXCVBN
```

I need each line to become it's own row in the database. I am using the following code to create the array and insert into the database:

```
public function update_giveaway($item_id) {

    // create array from comma separated string
    $post_keys = explode('\n', $this->input->post('giveaway_keys'));

    $db_keys = $this->get_giveaway_keys($item_id);

    // add tags to database that are in new array, but not in old array
    // returns array
    $add_keys = array_diff($post_keys, $db_keys);

    foreach($add_keys as $key) {

        // add to giveaway table
        $data = array(
          'giveaway_id' => $item_id,
          'key' => $key,
        );

    $this->db->set('date_created', 'NOW()', FALSE);
    $this->db->insert('atk_giveaways', $data);

    }

}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to use double quotes to define newlines as characters:

```
"\n"
```

Single quotes notate strings, double quotes notate characters

```
$post_keys = explode("\n", $this->input->post('giveaway_keys'));
```