# Special character to explode new lines of a file read with CI File Helper

Tags: php, file, codeigniter

Good afternoon.

So i have this issue with CodeIgniter.

Im reading a file using the file helper of CI

```
$this->load->helper('file');
$data = read_file('file.txt');
```

The problem is that the line

```
$data = read_file('file.txt');
```

returns a string with all the content of the file and I need to read each line of the file to make some operations.

I just tried this:

```
$data_array=  explode('\n',$data);
```

But when i do

```
sizeof($data_array);
```

its output is 1.

So. What is the special character that i need to use in order to properly explode the string?

Thanks in advance for the answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `\n\r` with double quotes (not single quotes):

```
$data_array = explode("\n\r", $data);
```

Comment: It works properly now. And just for the record, there is a similar topic here 
[from Motive User](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11904862/exploding-textarea-contents-by-new-line-using-n-but-array-not-being-created?rq=1)
(Same problem in different situation)

Comment: I'm sure this question (or similar) has been asked multiple times :)

Comment: Sure it has been, but i thought it was a CI function problem or something. Just forgot the double quotes and single quotes mean in PHP

Answer (score 0):

Line endings are depend on operation system, they can be `\n`, `\r`, `\n\r` or `\r\n` in different systems

So, you can either use [file](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file.php) or [mb_split](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mb-split.php) with `[\r\n]+` as pattern